# V4 user permission not working with other relation

Tags: reactjs, strapi

- Strapi Version: 4.6.2
- Operating System: Mac os
- Database: PostgreSQL

I have a problem with a user relation to a different entity.

I can send a request to retrieve the relation as written in the documentation.

In my case is

> owner = 1

1 is user id

```
 name: "asdf" menu : [...] <= here is relation with category and
 it's working correctly 
 owner: 2
 restaurantId: "d668fe5f-4746-4840-bb0e-1400295d0b1c"
```

[image: issue]

In strapi admin panel, I can't see the relation to the user when I send this from the front-end/postman, but the entity is created without this entry (owner). When I created this entity from the panel all worked correctly.

Payload:

[image]

Response:

[image]

I use latest version on PostgreSQL/strapi

Relation will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

In order to get owner data in the response after creation. You need to pass `populate="owner"` parameter to your request URL. For example:

For POST request:

```
/api/restaurants?populate="owner"
```

It also works for GET requests,

List:

```
/api/restaurants?populate="owner"
```

Single:

```
/api/restaurants/71?populate="owner"
```

There are also many ways to use populate parameter. You can find some advanced usage in this documentation: https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/api/rest/populate-select#population

Hope that helps!